# Navigation Component: Navigate from Fragment in Viewpager to another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I have a `Fragment A` which navigates to `Fragment B`

`Fragment B` hosts a `ViewPager2`.

`ViewPager2` has two fragments inflated in it - `Fragment C` and `Fragment D`.

On clicking an item in `Fragment C` I want to navigate to a new instance of `Fragment D` on top of `Fragment B`.

Currently, my code is something like this -

```
findNavController().navigate(
            R.id.action_FragmentC_to_FragmentD,
            bundleOf("id" to id, "type" to "list")
        )
```

However, when I try to navigate I get the following exception -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.test.at:id/action_FragmentC_to_FragmentD cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.krtkush.audiotime:id/FragmentB) label=FragmentB
```

From what I can understand is that the navigation component is still on `Fragment B` but I'm trying to navigate to `Fragment D` from `Fragment C` and hence it is throwing an exception.

I (think) can fix this by adding a listener which informs `Fragment B` when the item is tapped in  `Fragment C` and then navigate to `Fragment D` from `Fragment B`. However, this will make my `Fragment C` tightly coupled to `Fragment B` which I don't want to. Anyway to fix this is another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not `navigate()` to `Fragment C` and `Fragment D`, you will remain on the last destination you navigated to: `Fragment B`, that is the expected behavior. The NavController knows nothing about child fragments such as fragments within a ViewPager of `Fragment B` and therefore you were never on `Fragment C` as a destination.

If you never `navigate()` to `Fragment C` and it is only viewable as part of your ViewPager, then `Fragment C` should not **be** in your graph. Any actions from fragments within `Fragment B`'s ViewPager should be actions on `Fragment B` directly (the destination you're actually on).

Note that you can reuse the same actions names on fragments such as `Fragment D` if you are also using them as standalone destinations in your graph (thus ensuring that the action is available in both cases).

Comment: > "Any actions from fragments within Fragment B's ViewPager should be actions on Fragment B directly (the destination you're actually on)."

Does this not tightly couple the fragment to the host activity/ fragment?

Comment: You run the exact same `findNavController().navigate()` code, so I don't know what additional coupling you think is happening?

Comment: `Fragment C ` will have to inform `Fragment B` that an action has been taken and then `navigate()` will be called. Now, if I want to use `Fragment C` independently somewhere else within the app, it'll have no `Fragment B` to inform but actually call `navigate()` itself.

Comment: No, you don't need to do that at all - `Fragment C` can call `findNavController().navigate()` itself without any problems. Your action just needs to be on `Fragment B` when you are actually on `Fragment B`. As per the last paragraph, you can certainly use the same action name on `Fragment C` as well if you are using it independently of your ViewPager as well, all without changing `Fragment C`'s code.

Comment: how to inform fragment B from fragment C or fragment D. I am getting the same exception when I use @ianhanniballake suggestion.

Comment: @ianhanniballake no we cannot reuse same if `Fragment C` is opened standalone from some other `Fragment E`. In this case, `Fragment C` has a code that triggers on a button click `findNavController().navigate(FragmentBDirections.actiontoFragmentC())`. It will give exception that action is not found on Destination `Fragment E`.